# Self reference in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have table where I would like to have two self foreign keys as Next and Previous.

Here how it look like:

```
public class BoxDefinition : ISiblingable
    {
        public int BoxDefinitionId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Next")]
        public int? NextId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Previous")]
        public int? PreviousId { get; set; }

        public BoxDefinition Next { get; set; }
        public BoxDefinition Previous { get; set; }
        //public virtual ICollection<BoxDefinition> NextSiblings { get; set; }
        //public virtual ICollection<BoxDefinition> PreviousSiblings { get; set; }

        public static BoxDefinition GetById(int id, IContext context)
        {
            return context.BoxDefinitions.SingleOrDefault(b => b.BoxDefinitionId == id);
        }
    }
```

When I uncomment these two collections everything is working but in this entity I do need many because every instance has just ONE next and previous or null.

Here is the error:

> BoxDefinition_Previous_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role
>   'BoxDefinition_Previous_Target' in relationship
>   'BoxDefinition_Previous'. Because the Dependent Role properties are
>   not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the
>   Dependent Role must be '*'.

Entity Framework may think that there should be Collection because there could be many references but I know it won't.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you should add `InverseProperty` attribute:

```
public class BoxDefinition : ISiblingable
{
     //other stuff....
     [ForeignKey("Next")]
     [Index(IsUnique = true)]        
     public int? NextId { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("Previous")]
     [Index(IsUnique = true)]        
     public int? PreviousId { get; set; }

     public BoxDefinition Next { get; set; }
     public BoxDefinition Previous { get; set; }

     [Obsolete]
     [InverseProperty("Next")]
     public virtual ICollection<BoxDefinition> NextSiblings { get; set; }

     [Obsolete]
     [InverseProperty("Previous")]
     public virtual ICollection<BoxDefinition> PreviousSiblings { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, you should to declare these properties for proper navigation, but you can simply ignore them and mark with `Obsolete` attribute for remaining about this fact. Also you can add unique indexes to `NextId` and `PreviousId` fields to ensure that relation will be only as one-to-one.